# testing a method's parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

How can I test a method's parameter?

```
 def create_person child

 end
```

Above code is my method. It takes a parameter named "child". I try to test this parameter. So, if method doesn't take parameter, test will give me error. I use minitest and Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`assert_raises`](http://bfts.rubyforge.org/minitest/MiniTest/Assertions.html#method-i-assert_raises) to test if an `ArgumentError` is raised

```
assert_raises ArgumentError do
  YourClass.create_person
end
```